# Saving sytem Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, save

I am making a simple IDLE game in html but I really want to make a saving system. So I tried with `localStorage` but if I open my webpage there just comes `NaN`... Anybody knows how to fix it?

code:

```
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("Money", Money);
    localStorage.setItem("DrinksSold", DrinksSold);
    localStorage.setItem("Price", Price);
    localStorage.setItem("Plants", Plants);
    localStorage.setItem("CompetitorBonus", CompetitorBonus);
    localStorage.setItem("Meals", Meals);
    localStorage.setItem("MealsLeft", MealsLeft);
    localStorage.setItem("MealCost", MealCost);
    localStorage.setItem("Werknemers", Werknemers);
    localStorage.setItem("WerknemerCost", WerknemerCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextCostWerknemer", nextCostWerknemer);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicenses", StreetLicenses);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicensesHomeTown", StreetLicensesHomeTown);
    localStorage.setItem("StreetLicenseCost", StreetLicenseCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextCostStreetLicense", nextCostStreetLicense);
    localStorage.setItem("HigherPriceCost", HigherPriceCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextHigherPriceCost", nextHigherPriceCost);
    localStorage.setItem("PlantCost", PlantCost);
    localStorage.setItem("nextPlantCost", nextPlantCost);   
    localStorage.setItem("nextMealCost", nextMealCost);
    localStorage.setItem("DestroyCompetitorCost", DestroyCompetitorCost);
}


function load_game(){
    if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("game_saved_before")) != undefined){
    Money = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Money"));
    DrinksSold = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("DrinksSold"));
    Price = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Price"));
    Plants = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Plants"));
    CompetitorBonus = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("CompetitorBonus"));
    Meals = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Meals"));
    MealsLeft = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("MealsLeft"));
    MealCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("MealCost"));
    Werknemers = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("Werknemers"));
    WerknemerCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("WerknemerCost"));
    nextCostWerknemer = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextCostWerknemer"));
    StreetLicenses = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicenses"));
    StreetLicensesHomeTown = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicensesHomeTown"));
    StreetLicenseCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("StreetLicenseCost"));
    nextCostStreetLicense = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextCostStreetLicense"));
    HigherPriceCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("HigherPriceCost"));
    nextHigherPriceCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextHigherPriceCost"));
    PlantCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("PlantCost"));
    nextPlantCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextPlantCost"));
    nextMealCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("nextMealCost"));
    DestroyCompetitorCost = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("DestroyCompetitorCost"));
    localStorage.setItem("game_saved_before","true");
    }
}
load_game();
setInterval(save,10);
```

I know that `NaN` 'not a number' means and I searched through the internet but couldn't find any possible way for getting numbers? I used `parseInt` but that doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: are you sure you're only storing numbers?

Comment: try without parse int and lets see what your are actually trying to store

Comment: There must be a mistake somewhere in your code... `localStorage.setItem("test", "1");

console.log(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("test")) + 2);`

Gives me the expected result of 3.

Comment: It is working for me are you sure your browser is compatible ?

Comment: I use Google chrome so I think my browser is correct... Yes I am only storing numbers!

Comment: These are some of the variables... Do I have to declare them in an other way?    var Money = 100, DrinksSold = 0, Price = 1, Plants = 1,       CompetitorBonus = 1, CompetitorsLeft = 1;
     var Meals = 1, MealsLeft = 2, MealCost = 750000;